# Why won't one of my components hide onclick using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

For the life of me I can't figure out why the `Spin Now` won't hide upon clicking it.  It rightfully shows `Claim Now` upon clicking `Spin Now` but once `Claim Now` shows, I want the `Spin Now` to hide.  I'm using hooks, what am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SpinNowButton from '../../components/SpinNowButton/SpinNowButton';
import ClaimNowButton from '../../components/ClaimNowButton/ClaimNowButton';
import './Buttons.css';

const Buttons = () => {
    const [showSpin, setShowSpin] = useState(false);
    const [showClaim, setShowClaim] = useState(false);

    return(
        <div className="both-buttons">
            <SpinNowButton onClick={() => setShowClaim(true)}/>
            {showClaim ? <ClaimNowButton/> : null}
            {showSpin ? <SpinNowButton/> : null}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Buttons;
```

Comment: ~You want to toggle between  `<ClaimNowButton/>` and `<SpinNowButton/>`?

Comment: @Dupocas something like that, so for example, when I click SpinNow, I want ClaimNow to show but I also want SpinNow to hide.  That's my issue.

Comment: one ternary seems like a better option `{showClaim ? <ClaimNowButton/> : <SpinNowButton/>}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you only need one piece of state to accomplish this, and you set it to the opposite of what the value was previously. Then the ternary components below will render one component if true, and the other if false.

**Edit - I think this is closer to what you're looking for:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SpinNowButton from '../../components/SpinNowButton/SpinNowButton';
import ClaimNowButton from '../../components/ClaimNowButton/ClaimNowButton';
import './Buttons.css';

const Buttons = () => {
    const [showClaim, setShowClaim] = useState(false);

    const handleCLick = () => {setShowClaim(!showClaim)}

    return(
        <div className="both-buttons">
            {showClaim ? null : <SpinNowButton onClick{() => handleClick()}/>}
            {showClaim ? <ClaimNowButton onClick{() => handleClick()}/> : null}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Buttons;
```

Answer (score 0):

An implementation which is flexible in adding more types such as claim/spin:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SpinNowButton from '../../components/SpinNowButton/SpinNowButton';
import ClaimNowButton from '../../components/ClaimNowButton/ClaimNowButton';
import './Buttons.css';

const Buttons = () => {
    const [shownItems, setShownItems] = useState(['spin']);

    return(
        <div className="both-buttons">
            {shownItems.contains('claim') && <ClaimNowButton onClick={() => setShownItems('spin')}/>}
            {shownItems.contains('spin') && <SpinNowButton onClick={() => setShownItems('claim')}/>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Buttons;
```